# Why is installing ZFS as a root filesystem no longer an option

Tags: boot

On the page of the installer where it would ask you what kind of installation you wanted there used to be a button labeled 'advanced' where you could install with LVM or ZFS. That is gone now.

[image: installation type page]

Answer (score 2):

You may have found this by now, but the option to use ZFS is on *the next page*

[image: Where Be ZFS?]

These screenshots were taken after loading the Ubuntu Desktop 21.04 ISO into a Live Session with the following minimal specs:

- 2 CPU cores (with PAE/NX)
- 2GB RAM
- 120GB dynamically allocated storage (set as SSD)
- EFI enabled

To the best of my knowledge, there isn't a minimum set of hardware required for the ZFS option to appear.

Comment: ZFS is vey memory heavy- Both the ARC and if you uses advanced options like de duplication and compression. 2 GB RAM is not enough to get good performance under any significant   load. But maybe okay for playing and learning.

Comment: Indeed. I never said that 2GB was any good, just that the option appeared. Ideally any modern OS would have at least 8GB of RAM for the graphical environment, seemingly-mandatory web browsers, and underlying file system 